# Does "The whole language always available" hold in case of Clojure?

Tags: programming-languages, clojure, lisp, common-lisp

Ninth bullet point in Paul Graham's [What Made Lisp Different](http://www.paulgraham.com/diff.html) says,

> **9. The whole language always available.**
>
> There is no real distinction between read-time, compile-time, and runtime. You can compile or run code while reading, read or run code while compiling, and read or compile code at runtime.
>
> Running code at read-time lets users reprogram Lisp's syntax; running code at compile-time is the basis of macros; compiling at runtime is the basis of Lisp's use as an extension language in programs like Emacs; and reading at runtime enables programs to communicate using s-expressions, an idea recently reinvented as XML.

Does this last bullet point hold for Clojure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can mix runtime and compile-time freely in Clojure, although Common Lisp is still somewhat more flexible here (due to the presence of compiler macros and symbol macros and a fully supported `macrolet`; Clojure has an advantage in its cool approach to macro hygiene through automagic symbol resolution in syntax-quote). The reader is currently closed, so the free mixing of runtime, compile-time *and* read-time is not possible<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except through unsupported [clever hacks](http://briancarper.net/blog/449/).

Comment: Just to be clear, it is possible in Clojure to `read` code at arbitrary times and then compile and execute it; it is not, however, possible to plug into the reader to execute arbitrary code at read-time, as it is in Common Lisp.

Comment: Love the hack. Thanks for the link! :-D

Comment: Clojure can execute arbitrary code at read-time with the `#=` reader macro.

Comment: @Stuart Sierra: Thanks for the comment, I should have mentioned that! Still, that's nothing close to a programmable reader, which is what I understand PG's point to be about (you can't use `#=` to "reprogram [Clojure]'s syntax"). Also, it's a terrible safety hazard (and `*read-eval*` being `true`  by default seems to me to be rather a misfeature); which is of course a very good reason to want to mention it in contexts like the present one, so thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

It does hold,

```
(eval (read-string "(println \"Hello World!!\")"))
Hello World!!
nil
```

Just like emacs you can have your program configuration in Clojure, one project that I know Clojure for is [static](http://github.com/nakkaya/static) which allows you to have your template as a Clojure vector along with arbitrary code which will be executed at read time.